# Displaying sudoku grid with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, lines, sudoku

I have wrote a c program to solve sudokus, and i would like to know if i can draw the grid and fill it using ncurses library.
i just would like to know how to control the lines and borders of boxes in ncurses

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using `hline` family of functions to draw your grid.

See http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/man/html.CURSES/hline.CURSES.html for more information.